# Why are operators often written in 3s?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

In a lot of my quantum mechanics and linear algebra books, operators are often defined as 
$M=IMI$ 
and many operations on operators are often done in similar fashion, for eg. operator $M$ might be sandwhiched between $H$ and $H^+$ (hermitian conjugate of H). 
What does $M=IMI$ mean and why is it written like that? 
Here is another 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN0l9.png).

Comment: That is not a _definition_ of $M$. It is simply an equaton that always holds. (For those that can't be bothered to click on the link: In the linked example, $I$ is expressed as $P+Q$, and then $M=(P+Q)M(P+Q)$ is expanded and clever things are deduced.)

Comment: In a nutshell: if $H$ is invertible, then $HMH^{-1}$ is a [similar matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) to $M$ and $HMH^\dagger$ is a [congruent matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) to $M$.  If $H$ is unitary, then we can have both.  Matrix similarity comes out of studying linear transformations under changes of basis, and matrix congruence comes out of studying bilinear forms under changes of basis.